Jailbreaking Vantron 5081G tablet
I have a Vantron Tech Tablet model 5081G with Rockchip 3366H processor. All the settings are locked. My PC doesn't recognize it as a USB device. In recovery mode, the only option is to reboot.
Can anyone help me to unlock it?

What is the history of this device? Has it been owned by anyone before you? Could it be a device that had belonged to a child and is still under Family Link control?

Browsing about Vantron Technology, looks like they're producing industrial-oriented tablets, so it might be locked down to prevent damages. I kind of doubt if it's possible to root it, considering that there are many specialized Android ROM+firmware that behave like this.

@johndallman it was prison tablet and presumably still running it's intended system

@Andrew T is there any else I can do in order to make it function like a normal tablet without any restrictions?
